# What should the second param of `simulate` accept?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I know in `simulate` we can normally do something like:

```
simulate("change", { target: { value: '7' } });
```

But what do I pass in the second parameter if my `onChange` function accepts an object as the parameter?

```
interface myObject{
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

myChangeFunction(item: myObject) {
   /* */
}
```

Please note that I tried:

```
const updates = { firstname: "john", lastname: "doe" };
simulate("change", { target: updates });

and

simulate("change", updates );
```

But it failed to work.

Comment: Can you share the "change" event function implementation.

Comment: it simply updates another state property with `item.firstname`. I left it out for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The `simulate` function simulates events, and your `myChangeFunction` expects an `item` as param instead of `event`.

Not sure how you're defining your `onChange` in your component, but if you try to change only your interface into something like:

```
interface myObject {
  target: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
  }
}

myChangeFunction(item: myObject) {
   // here should output { firstname: "john", lastname: "doe" }
   console.log(item.target);  
}
```

and

```
const updates = { firstname: "john", lastname: "doe" };
simulate("change", { target: updates });
```